# ionic 2 FileOpener, mime-type is null

Tags: ios, ionic2

i use FileTransfer-Plugin to download a file over a API. After download i want open the file with FileOpener-Plugin. FileOpener requires the mime-type of the file, but data.type (mime-type) returns null.

```
File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(cordova.file.cacheDirectory)
    .then((dirEntry) => {

      this.transfer.download(url, path, true, {headers: headers})

        .then((entry) => {

           entry.file((data) => {
               console.log('MimeType: ', data.type); // returns null
           });
        });
    });
```

it works without setting mime-type, but i think it is better with. Anybody knows about this Problem. I working in iOS.

data returns:

> end: 683008
>
> lastModified: 1497256786396.6
>
> lastModifiedDate: 1497256786396.6
>
> localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/cache/file.ext"
>
> name: "file.ext"
>
> size: 683008
>
> start: 0
>
> type: null

Comment: i see ther is an reportet issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8546)